# Theme TextField toolbar options

Tags: flutter

I have added dark mode support to my Flutter app but can't figure out how to get the toolbar text for text fields to be white. I assume it's configured through theming but I can't figure out which theme data to set. [image]

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your notifications also look black in a dark theme. I think you haven't properly implemented the basic config for the dark theme.

```dart
ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    // .........
),
```

Try the above code, it will automatically change the text to white.

The Theme Data with brightness dark will change the basic default theme data to dark and then you can edit it accordingly.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem